# Read the contents of the PDF file onto a webView

Tags: android, webview

In my project I have to load the contents of a PDF located in the assets folder onto a WebView.Can It be achieved directly just by reading the contents onto a WebView.. I googled a lot and I found that i need to use third party PDF readers to achieve the same?

If so, Plz give me the links of the source of the PDF reader of GITHUB. Am not able to find it..

Answer (score 1):

If you load pdf inside the webview, unicode text type or images wont be visible. So you want

to go for OCR tool.

Use set of libraries and sdk

This might help you

http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/

http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply. Are there any PDF libraries or executable JARS which I can integrate with my project and implement. Please provide me the link of the Github PDF reader library.

Answer (score 1):

mupdf is the best library in terms of performance and all i have found till now, you can also use it in your application. 
But it needs knowledge of ndk.

[Click here for more description](https://github.com/muennich/mupdf/tree/master/android)